# What do PHP stream contexts do in relation to file operations?

Tags: php, file-io

In the PHP manual, the file operations reference an optional context (e.g. for [copy](https://www.php.net/copy)).  How do these contexts affect basic file operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, stream contexts can contain both [options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.php) and [parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-params.php).  At the current time, parameters are simply callback functions so that you can be notified at various points of the file operation.  Options are wrapper-specific, and filesystem operations don't have any options.  Some examples of options for the HTTP wrapper are method, proxy, etc.